# Atata - How to send keys to a page

Tags: c#, atata

I am new to Atata and trying to send say a TAB key to a page and verify the contents which is higlighted (like say on a Google page) . I know we can do like below on say a page using `Press` but could not figure a way to send the special keys like TAB , CTRL, ENTER and all

```
Go.To<ContactPage>().Press("abc");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Keys` class from `OpenQA.Selenium` namespace that contains all necessary keys, like below:

```
Go.To<ContactPage>().Press(Keys.Tab);
// Or
Go.To<ContactPage>().Press("abc" + Keys.Tab);
```

There is also unique Atata triggers feature. There are `[PressEnter]`, `[PressTab]`, `[PressEscape]` and `[PressKeys("abc")]` attributes. Trigger attribute will automatically press the specified key(s) after the value is set to control. For example:

```
public class SearchPage : Page<_>
{
    [FindById("search-query")]
    [PressEnter] // Adds trigger.
    public TextInput<_> Query { get; private set; }
}
```

And then test:

```
Go.To<SearchPage>().
    Query.Set("abc"); // Enter will be pressed after "abc" text is set.
```

Comment: thanks @yevgeniy-shunevych for your help again as this made it to work. Now I may need to get text from the highlighted object.

Comment: Welcome. Feel free to ask another questions. Please mark current answer as correct one.